# mhddfs only writing to first drive

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, partition, mariadb

I have around 60GB MySQL data to import, and a freshly installed MariaDB 10.0 in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have 3 of 50GB disk, each is mounted as `/mnt/hdd1`, `/mnt/hdd2`, `/mnt/hdd3`. Then I ran following command to combine all disks to one;

```
mkdir /mnt/virtual
mhddfs /mnt/hdd1,/mnt/hdd2,/mnt/hdd3 /mnt/virtual -o allow_other
```

Then following this tutorial, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04, I pointed the `datadir` of the MySQL to `/mnt/virtual/mysql`.

But when I ran my importing script, I am getting `ER_RECORD_FILE_FULL` error. Checking the disks using `df -h` giving me following output;

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none                           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          798M   22M  777M   3% /run
/dev/vda                        46G  1.3G   43G   3% /
tmpfs                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb                        46G   46G     0 100% /mnt/hdd1
/dev/vdc                        46G   52M   44G   1% /mnt/hdd2
/dev/vdd                        46G   52M   44G   1% /mnt/hdd3
/mnt/hdd1;/mnt/hdd2;/mnt/hdd3  138G   46G   87G  35% /mnt/virtual
```

Only first disk is filled up. It should automatically write to other unused disk instead. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I misunderstood how mhddfs works. In the end I have to choose either to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM for the database engine or LVM instead of mhddfs. So I'm using LVM following this tutorial, http://askubuntu.com/a/7841/407467

Answer (score 0):

You want RAID. Lvm and mhddfs will not provide performance or redundancy bonuses.